# Change image on radio button click using JS or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few radio buttons replaced with images. I have a second set of images I'd like the original ones to change to when a certain button is selected.

**HTML**

```
<label class="item">
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="size" required="required"/>
    <img src="./images/10.png"/>
</label>
...
```

**CSS**

```
label.item > input {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

In this case, the image is `10.png`. I'd like it to change to `10S.png` when selected, but revert back to `10.png` when another option is selected.

My best idea was to use JS to append an `S` to the end of the image path onclick, but reverting back proved troublesome. Is there a strictly HTML/CSS way to do it, or is JS a must? All images used for the radio buttons are in the form `#.png` from 1-10, and the updated images are `#S.png` from 1-10 (ie. 2.png will become 2S.png, etc).

I'd rather not use JQuery if possible and I'm hoping for a solution with the most browser compatibility.

Comment: I know you say not use of Jquery but take a lokk here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469789/changing-radio-buttons-image-help?rq=1

Comment: could you eventually merge the image 10 + 10s side by side? Doing so you could use `clip` property depending on the `:checked` status of the previous input

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan do you mean CSS sprites?

Comment: yes. doing so you could save several requests and obtain at the same time a preload for "free" of all `-s` images :)

Comment: I bet on pure CSS, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an HTML and CSS only solution using the `:checked` pseudo-class and a pseudo-element.

```css
label.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
label.item > input {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
label.item > .radio-image::before {
  content: url("http://placehold.it/50x50");
}
label.item > input[type="radio"]:checked + .radio-image::before {
  content: url("http://placehold.it/75x75");
}
```

```html
<label class="item">
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="size" required="required"/>
    <div class="radio-image"></div>
</label>
<label class="item">
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="size" required="required"/>
    <div class="radio-image"></div>
</label>
<label class="item">
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="size" required="required"/>
    <div class="radio-image"></div>
</label>
<label class="item">
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="size" required="required"/>
    <div class="radio-image"></div>
</label>
<label class="item">
    <input type="radio" value="10" name="size" required="required"/>
    <div class="radio-image"></div>
</label>
```

As far as I know, this is compatible in modern browsers and IE9+

Comment: How would I make it dynamic? Say I had five radio buttons, your solution suggests I would need to hardcode `content: url(#.png)` and `content; url(#S.png)` for all five buttons. Is there a solution where only two styles are needed instead of ten (for the example of five buttons)?

Comment: Edited to use multiple radio buttons.  If you want to dynamically populate the image URL's then you'll need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, allowing you to be very flexible and let the content in the HTML as you apparently need to :

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" value="10" id="size10" name="size" required="required"/>
<label for="size10" class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</label>
<input type="radio" value="15" id="size15" name="size" required="required"/>
<label for="size15" class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Hiding radio button */
input[type='radio'] {display:none;}
/* Hiding second image in label tags */
label.item > img:nth-child(2) {display:none;}
/* When radio-button is checked, display second image in the following label tag */
input[type='radio']:checked + label.item > img:nth-child(1) {display:none;}
input[type='radio']:checked + label.item > img:nth-child(2) {display:inline-block;}
```

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yuutq7h/) for demo.

Note I did move the radiobutton out of the label cause I like it better that way, and selectors will probably need to be adapted to your situation, but once you understand the logic it shouldn't be an issue.