# Can't fetch image and info from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to display image and details from database where i have stored. I have got code which connects to database but doesn't fetch.
Edited: Thanks guys i was able to fetch but I have incurred anther problem. I have stored image as blob. so when i queried it displayed some mumbojumbo language.
[screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K5kN.png)
[screenshot of how i stored image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX3J3.png)
    .......
    echo"Connected to db" ;

```
if (isset($_POST['info'])){
    $info= 'info';
    if ($info== 1){
        $sql= "SELECT name,img,price FROM product WHERE price<400";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<div class= 'row'>";
            echo    "<div class = 'col-sm-3'>";
            echo        "<p>".$row['img']."</p><br/>";
            echo        "<h3>".$row['name']."</h3><br/>";
            echo        "<h4>£".$row['price']."</h4><br/>";
            echo    "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }

exit();
```

Here is my jquery code where it prints the the output of checkbox and it echo connected to database  but can't fetch.

```
$(".id_price").each(function() {
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var check = $(this).val();
    console.log(check);
    $.post('database.php',{info:check},function(response){
        $(".product").html(response).show(); 

    });

}
```

});

Comment: you set `$info = 'info'` right before you check `if($info == 1)`. That would never go into the second `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo"Connected to db" ;

if (isset($_POST['info'])){
    $info= 'info'; // <----------------
    if ($info== 1){
        $sql= "SELECT name,img,price FROM product WHERE price<400";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<div class= 'row'>";
            echo    "<div class = 'col-sm-3'>";
            echo        "<p>".$row['img']."</p><br/>";
            echo        "<h3>".$row['name']."</h3><br/>";
            echo        "<h4>£".$row['price']."</h4><br/>";
            echo    "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }

exit();
```

You set `$info == "info"` and then check if `$info == 1`

Try this:

```
    .......
echo"Connected to db" ;

    if (isset($_POST['info'])){
                $sql= "SELECT name,img,price FROM product WHERE price<400";
                $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo "<div class= 'row'>";
                    echo    "<div class = 'col-sm-3'>";
                    echo        "<p>".$row['img']."</p><br/>";
                    echo        "<h3>".$row['name']."</h3><br/>";
                    echo        "<h4>£".$row['price']."</h4><br/>";
                    echo    "</div>";
                    echo "</div>";

            }
        }
        exit();
```

Comment: Thanks it queried but it displayed some random fonts like info  but not image.(i stored image as blob, does it affect?

Comment: if you want to show an image use this : echo "<img src='".$row['img']."'/>" , . You should store in database the URL of image (the path)

Comment: I used php admin for that. So while i was storing images, i copied and pasted the image as blob. I tried like you said but it still prints same. Also i have got screenshot above.

Comment: Your code is " echo        "<p>".$row['img']."</p><br/>";"  for the image, did you chanced the tags to "<img src='".$row['img']."'/>"   ?

Comment: You should take into account that the image's path is relative. Can you put the line of php code that echo the image, and an example of image's path which saved in database?

Comment: for php copied and pasted yours and screenshot is above. Thnx

Comment: still same result no image displayed but now it doesn't print random info, it just displays icon :(

Comment: if your image's path is  C://User/Desktop/image.jpg you can add all the path in database or you can move the image file to the htdocs folder  in same place with php code, and save in database only the image's name (image.jpg), then you can use this path in your php code like : echo "<img src='../".$row['image']."'/>";

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked now.You saved my life  :)

Comment: If you appreciate this answer, please do not forget to upvote and accept, to help other members which have the same question. You are welcome :)

Comment: One last question, how do i compare the different values of checkbox if i had to displayed the image according to the checked value?

Comment: may you are looking for : 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166862/change-image-on-radio-button-click-using-js-or-html

Answer (score 0):

```
$info= 'info';
if ($info== 1){
```

$info will always equal 'info' so it will not attempt the query.